# Declaring arrays as firstprivate in OpenMP - C

Tags: c, openmp

I'm beginning to dive into OpenMP and I'm not sure I fully understand how firstprivate would deal with arrays.

If I had code such as:

```
int array[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int i;    
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(array)
for (i=0; i<SOME_LENGTH; i++) {
  // something using array as a right hand operand
}
```

Would the array be copied to each thread? What if it was a more complex structure and not a simple `int`?

Is the memory itself copied or the values?

Also if you can point me in the direction of more documentation I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each thread gets its own instance of the variable, initialized to the value of that variable.

Documentation seems to be a bit sparse beside the original documentation and some basic tutorials.

Comment: Even though it's an array?

Answer (score 3):

As per 2.15.3.4 of [OpenMP 4.5](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf), the elements are copied:

> For an array of elements of non-array type, each element is initialized as if by assignment from an element of the original array to the corresponding element of the new array.